# pinentry implementation with fingerprint sensor support

Tags: xcode, git, macos, gnupg

Currently, I am using `Pinentry Mac` from Xcode on my system to sign git commits. For this, I am having to input my passphrase each time I am waiting to sign a commit.

[image: Xcode Pinentry]

Seeing that my MacBook Pro has a fingerprint sensor I was wondering if there is a pinentry implementation can substitute password entry with a fingerprint check?

Comment: Are you really more worried about someone pushing a git commit than having access to you machine? If not, it seems sensible to beef up the security as much as possible (e.g. setting it to timeout faster when unattended) and save your git password so you don't have to reenter it.

Comment: Basically, you want to use fingerprint every time Pinentry Mac alert pop up to bypass?

Answer (score 0):

THere is no fingerprint support that I can see.

There is however, [from this thread](https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/58498-gpgservices-pinentry-mac-keeps-asking-for-passphrase), passphrase caching (meaning you enter only once, and never again after that)

See "[GPGTools Support / Password management](https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/kb/faq/password-management)".

Make sure your `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` does *not* include the line `ignore-cache-for-signing`.

Comment: This does not answer my question. I am aware I can save the password, but I want to be asked each time again and be able to confirm this via fingerprint.

Comment: @Empty2k12 "able to confirm this via fingerprint": I don't know of any implementation of GPG tool which supports a fingerprint. "I want to be asked each time again": that is the default mode... but again without fingerprint support. Hence my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation of `pinentry` that supports this use-case: https://github.com/jorgelbg/pinentry-touchid